# Algorithms used in Collision detection, Rigid Body Simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

I had a school project done in Blender using Rigid Body simulation where obviously collision detection plays a huge role and I want to be able to explain in better detail how it all works in the background.

Basically, what I am looking for are the algorithms and techniques that Blender uses to accomplish this. I've already tried googling, the docs, discord but without luck. Now, I've read a few papers about collision detection and rigid body dynamics but I need something more specific related to Blender.

I will highly appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Blender is open source, what better way to understand algorithms then to actually read them firsthand from the source code?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hmm, that was right in front of my eyes the whole time. Your input led me to a search and eventually found out Blender uses bullet2 for physics and collision. That's great for a start, thanks a lot.